# Como clonar un elemento aleatorio

Tags: javascript, php, html

estoy intentando hacer un scroll infinito, y para ello se me ha ocurrido hacer una función a la que se llama cuando se desliza, y que clona el div que quiero que aparezca. El problema que este div contiene datos aleatorios, y cuando lo clono, pone el mismo dato. ¿Hay alguna solución? ¿Cómo podría hacerlo sino? He mirado muchas otras formas de hacer un scroll infinito perro no me funciona ninguna. Agradezco cualquier cosa.Muchas gracias de antemano.
Este es el código que estoy usando:

```
<script>
        function ajax(){
        const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const url = 'http://localhost/Registro/articulo.php';
        http.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
              console.log(this.responseText);
              document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                var clonarticulo = $('#articulo').clone();
                $('#articulo').after(clonarticulo);
                
            }
        }
        
        http.open("GET", url);
        http.send();
          
    }
    


    $(document).ready(function(){
        var count=0;

        // evento que se ejecuta cuando se mueve el scroll de la pagina
        $(document).scroll(function(){
 
            // si esl scroll de la pagina mas la altura es superior
            // a la altura del documento
            if($(document).scrollTop()+$(window).height()>=$(document).height())
            {
                // Aqui podria ir una función ajax para cargar el contenido
                // de base de datos o de PHP...

                count+=1;
                // añadimos al final de la página unas lineas de ejemplo
                $("body").append( "<article>",ajax(),"</article><article>",ajax(),"</article><article>",ajax(),"</article>");
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Y este es el div que quiero clonar:

```
<div class= "articulo" id="articulo"> 
         <article>
          <?php $sql="SELECT*FROM publicaciones ORDER BY RAND() limit 1";
              $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
              while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
                $publicacion=$mostrar['publicacion'];
                ?>
                <?php } ?>
            <hgroup>
                <div id="user" onclick="location.href='Perfil.php'"><img src="Imagenes/Foto de perfil - copia.png" id="fotouser">
                  <h1 id="nombreuser">
                <?php $sql="SELECT*FROM publicaciones WHERE publicacion= '".$publicacion."' ORDER BY RAND() limit 1";
              $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
              while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
                $autor= ucfirst($mostrar['nombre']);?> 
              <?php echo $autor ?> 
              <?php } ?>
              </h1></button>
              </div>
              <h1 id="Tituloarticulo">Título del primer artículo</h1>
            </hgroup>
              <time datetime="08-02-2021"> Publicado el 08-02-2021</time>
              <p><table>
              <?php
              $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
              while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
                ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $mostrar['publicacion'] ?> </td>
              <tr> 
              <?php 
              }
              ?>
              </table></p>
                  <im src="Imagenes/Aerodinamica vaca Fondo.png"/>
              <footer> 
                  <p>Comentarios (0)</p>
                  <button id="Comentarios"></button>
              </footer>
          </article>
          </div>
          <div id="response">
          </div>
```

Comment: Buenas, Mariguuan, bienvenid@ al sitio. Un par de apuntes. No se entiende muy bien el problema, si clonas algo te saldrá una copia de lo que tienes, con los mismos datos ¿Qué datos pretendes que muestre el clon? E infiero que tu pregunta se refiere a clonar con javascript, no? Si es así, edita y elimina las etiquetas no relacionadas como java y mysql, que no tienen nada que ver.

Comment: @RubioRic Acabo de entenderlo. ¿Y existe entonces alguna forma de clonar únicamente el código?